# Magnific Popup and Bootstrap 3 Modal Call Stack Exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, stack-overflow, magnific-popup

I'm having an interesting issue when combining Boostrap 3 Modal with Magnific Popup. I have a Bootstrap Modal that contains a list of videos, and each video has a view link that opens up a Magnific Popup iframe popup.

Everything worked fine until I played with Magnific Popup's `z-index` in order to get it to appear on top of the Bootstrap Modal. **Problem is**, if you try and close the Magnific Popup (or interact with it at all) a stackoverflow error occurs (Maximum call stack exceeded).

Note: Everything works fine if I leave the `z-index` of the Magnific Popup alone.

Simplified Example: http://codepen.io/craigh/pen/GoWWOK/

Note: codepen suppresses SO errors, so the issue is not as obvious. But on my site, the SO occurs locking the browser up.

I think it has something to do with how clicking outside of a Bootstrap Modal closes the modal, but I changed the modal backdrop to static (forces user to click the x or close button) but no change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted the answer to this question in a [github issue](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/796) about this same problem. Commenting out a line of code seems messing it does do the trick and I haven't found any side effects as of now.

Taken from github user RandomArray's response

> Line 375 seems to be the problem. I commented it out and the Maximum
>   call stack size exceeded error went away.
>
> _document.on('focusin' + EVENT_NS, mfp._onFocusIn);

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do meddle in the magnific popup code,
github user alyak46141414 later suggests in the same [issue](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/796#issuecomment-306294492)

> so , I did
>
> $(document).off('focusin' );
>
> after after magnific load ( any funcrion called after it loaded , you
>   may do inside .ready(). it clear all 'focusin' handlers . no magnific
>   popup code modification need .

Both this and Craig Harschbarger's (your) answer worked for me.